# TableView with section & Index on Android

Tags: android

How to achieve Tableview with section and Index on Section, similar to how it's done on the iPhone?

Comment: have a look at this link. i may answer your question.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4540754/add-dynamically-elements-to-a-listview-android

Answer (score 0):

I don't have examples in mind but I think it can be done quite easily by creating the headers in your xml and then adding dynamically the rows with an incremental variable int giving you the index.
The other option would be to do that with list in android. The final look would be pretty much the same as on the Iphone...
You can have a look at [this](http://jsharkey.org/blog/2008/08/18/separating-lists-with-headers-in-android-09/), it's pretty easy actually.