# Android Add Contact Form dynamically

Tags: android, forms, list, dynamic

[image]

Hi,

I want to implement form like in the image,  dont have idea how they are adding Fields dynamically. Is this a ListView? Expandable List? user can add and remove at runtime. I have checked Expandable List which contains child items. but we define child in array, In the image they add dynamically.

Any guide/link

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Custom `ListView` `Adapters` are often back by Collections, like `List`, `ArrayList`, etc. These lists may contain your custom objects, where the `Adapter` determines what to display based on the object properties. The lists can be managed/altered in typical fashions, like `add()` `remove()`, etc.

Do a Google search for "android custom list adapters" to learn more.

Here is an example of dynamically creating list rows with a "plus" buttons to add more rows. Should give you a good start: [Dynamically add elements to a listView Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4540754/add-dynamically-elements-to-a-listview-android)

You can always look at the source of the Android contacts app, as well.

Comment: Hi, I have tried different tutorials, but problem is how to add and remove content in the place of Item at runtime.

Comment: Like in the image, Email Group has add and remove button.

Comment: Did you check the link I added above? It appears that you need to brush up on Java, first. This method dynamically adds list items `public void addItems(View v) { listItems.add("Clicked : "+clickCounter++); adapter.notifyDataSetChanged(); }`. Removing would simple be something like `listItems.remove(index); adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();`