# Android add edittext field on click of (+) button and remove by click of (-)

Tags: android, android-edittext

I am creating a add contact activity. There will be only one edit text and a button (+), when click on button then another edit text should be added and previous button should change into (-). By this method i want to add and remove edit text fields.[Some thing like this.](http://www.google.co.in/imgres?q=android%20add%20contact&hl=en&safe=active&tbo=d&noj=1&tbm=isch&tbnid=SDkjnonb2GU7GM:&imgrefurl=https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9732783/android-add-contact-form-dynamically&docid=4NU7riH2qdlSVM&imgurl=https://i.stack.imgur.com/CCmqj.jpg&w=640&h=572&ei=eRgiUYvYFITrrQeqoICIBA&zoom=1&ved=1t:3588,r:3,s:0,i:90&iact=rc&dur=1806&sig=111728917285653940940&page=1&tbnh=171&tbnw=191&start=0&ndsp=24&tx=76&ty=79&biw=1366&bih=664) I am doing like this but not able to achieve that i want. Any idea?

```
public class TextField extends Activity {

Context con;
TableLayout table;
TableRow tr[] = new TableRow[6];
EditText txt[] = new EditText[6];
//ImageView img[] = new ImageView[5];
Button img[]=new Button[6];
int count ;
int lastDeletedIndex;
int lastPopulatedIndex;
boolean isDel;
public void onCreate(Bundle obj) {
    super.onCreate(obj);
    // Log.d("","On Create");
    con = this;
    count = 1;

    table = new TableLayout(this);
    tr[count] = new TableRow(this);
    tr[count].setId(count);
    tr[count].setLayoutParams(new TableRow.LayoutParams(    LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));

    txt[count] = new EditText(this);
    txt[count].setId(count);
    txt[count].setText("1");
    txt[count].setMaxLines(1);
    txt[count].setWidth(160);

        img[count] = new Button(this);
        img[count].setId(count);
        img[count].setText("+");
        img[count].setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.add);
        img[count].setPadding(5, 7, 20, 0);


    tr[count].addView(txt[count]);
    tr[count].addView(img[count]);
    tr[count].setPadding(20, 20, 0, 0);

    img[count].setOnClickListener(new OnClick(img[count]));

    table.addView(tr[count]);
    setContentView(table);

}

class OnClick implements OnClickListener {

    View view;

    Button addIcon;

    public OnClick(View view) {

        this.addIcon = (Button) view;

    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View arg0) {

            int id=addIcon.getId();
        if(addIcon.getText().toString().equals("-"))
        {

            if ((id >1  )) {
                isDel=true;
                count=id;
                lastDeletedIndex=id;
                txt[count]=null;
                img[count]=null;
                table.removeView(tr[count]);
                tr[count]=null;
                Log.d("", "Cancel img Id" + addIcon.getId());
                }       


        } else {
            if (count <5) {
                if(table.getChildCount()!=5)
                {
                    addIcon.setBackgroundDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.delete));
                    addIcon.setText("-");


                addIcon.setId(count);
                if(!isDel) {
                    count++;
                }else
                {
                    count=lastDeletedIndex;
                }


                tr[count] = new TableRow(con);
                tr[count].setId(count);


                    img[count] = new Button(con);
                img[count].setId(count);
                img[count].setBackgroundDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.add));
                img[count].setText("+");
                img[count].setPadding(3, 7, 20, 0);
                img[count].setOnClickListener(new OnClick(img[count]));

                txt[count] = new EditText(con);
                txt[count].setId( count);
                txt[count].setText(""+count);
                txt[count].setMaxLines(1);
                txt[count].setWidth(160);

                tr[count].addView(txt[count]);

                tr[count].addView(img[count]);

                tr[count].setPadding(20, 20, 0, 0);
                table.addView(tr[count]);
                setContentView(table);
                isDel=false;

                lastPopulatedIndex=count;

                Log.d("", "Cancel img Id" + addIcon.getId());
                }
            } else
                ShowDialog.showAlert("Info","You can't add more than 5 contacts!", con);
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: have you seen sdk samples there you can find good example of this

Comment: Yes, you need to start reading 'Android: dynamically creating layouts for dummies'. If you have a more specific question, please come back and ask it here!

Comment: have you used child view with edittext  that will be easy to add and remove the view in button click..

Comment: I have tried and its working but not very much accurate, there is some mismatch of ids.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
private void addEditView() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
          LinearLayout li=new LinearLayout(this);
          EditText et=new EditText(this);
          Button b=new Button(this);

          b.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                int pos=(Integer) v.getTag();
                mainLayout.removeViewAt(pos);

            }
        });

          b.setTag((mainLayout.getChildCount()+1));
    }
```

call this function when you click on a addEditText button.

Comment: i am already doing like this. but there is a very bigg prob and that is id of components. "button.setonClickListener(new onClickListener()" here i button is created dynamically and a dynamic id id given, how can i compare the id which i do not know..

Comment: setTag to it as true and get it back from getTag.

Comment: what ids are you talking about here I don't get you.

Comment: i have add my code please check it.i am very confused not able to understand what i did.

Comment: your code is a disaster please check my edit it will surely help

Comment: sorry bro not able to understand.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/24705/discussion-between-aashish-and-deepsan)

Comment: I want to implement this can you please see my [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/73090637/6854117)?

Answer (score 2):

Use this code in your activity :

```
@Override
public boolean dispatchKeyEvent(KeyEvent event) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

     if (event.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_PLUS)
     {
            if (event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN && event.getRepeatCount() == 0)
            {
                LinearLayout mLinearLayout = new LinearLayout(this);
                mLinearLayout = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.mylinearlayout);

                                EditText lEditText = new EditText(this);
                            lEditText.SetText("Text Here");
                            mLinearLayout.addView(lEditText);

                    }
            }
    return super.dispatchKeyEvent(event);
}
```

Comment: I am trying to do the same but it's not working

Comment: I want to implement this can you please see my [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/73090637/6854117)?

Answer (score 0):

You should create Android Layout(maybe LinearLayout or TableLayout) and than create view in java code(Android Activity)

Simple example;

View **view** = new View(this);

If view create successfully you can add this code --> .addView(**view**);
or
if view already added you can remove this code sample --> .removeView(**view**);