# how can I save the time from a chronometer into a listview?

Tags: android

I have created a chronometer with three buttons, "start", "stop" and "reset". once I stop the time I want that time to be save into a second activity which would be a ListView.

```
public class TrackerScreen extends ActionBarActivity {
Chronometer Timer;
long saveTime;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_tracker_screen);
    Button button;
    Timer = (Chronometer) findViewById(R.id.chronometer);

    button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.start);
    button.setOnClickListener(mStartListener);

    button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.stop);
    button.setOnClickListener(mStopListener);

    button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.reset);
    button.setOnClickListener(mResetListener);
}

View.OnClickListener mStartListener = new OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        Timer.setBase(SystemClock.elapsedRealtime());
        Timer.start();
    }
};

View.OnClickListener mStopListener = new OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        Timer.stop();
        saveTime = Timer.getBase() - SystemClock.elapsedRealtime();
    }
};

View.OnClickListener mResetListener = new OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        Timer.setBase(SystemClock.elapsedRealtime());
    }
};
```

then this is my ListView code

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_table_screen);
    String[] time = new String[6];
    for(int i = 0; time.length > i; i++){
            time[i] = "time";
    }

    ListView lv = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView);
    StringArrayAdapter ad = new StringArrayAdapter(time,this);
    lv.setAdapter(ad);
}
```

this is my StringArrayApdapter

```
public class StringArrayAdapter extends BaseAdapter{
String[] times;
Context ctxt;
LayoutInflater myInflater;
//constructor
public StringArrayAdapter(String[] array, Context c){
    times = array;
    ctxt = c;
    myInflater = (LayoutInflater)c.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

}
@Override
public int getCount() {
    return times.length;
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int i) {
    //return times at position
    return times[i];
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int i) {
    return 0;
}

@Override
public View getView(int i, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
    if(view == null)
        view = myInflater.inflate(android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,viewGroup,false);
    TextView time = (TextView)view.findViewById(android.R.id.text1);
    time.setText(times[i]);

    return view;
}
```

}

Comment: Which part is giving you trouble? Sending the time to the second activity or putting that time in the listview?

Comment: putting that time in a listview. using a loop. so I want to create a fourth button that would send the time to the next available space in a listview. hopes that makes sense. thanks!

Comment: Do you know how to make the listView and just need help adding to it?

Comment: just need help adding to it.

Comment: So do you know how you will send the time to the other activity?

Comment: nope I don't. I just added the rest of my code. Sorry that I wasn't able to provide the codes earlier. I didn't know how to.

Comment: No I don't know how to send the time to the other activity. how can I do that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your chronometer `Activity` (the one in which the user can start, stop, and reset the time), you could attach an onClickListener to the stop button, in which you include the following code:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                ActivityWithListViewName.class).putExtra("nameOfKey", someInt);
startActivity(intent);
```

Then, in your new activity with the `ListView`, you can get the values you send with `.putExtra()` with:

```
int seconds = getIntent().getExtras().getInt("nameOfKey");
```

The above line should return the value sent using the key `"nameOfKey"`

Comment: okay so I input the code you provide and when I stop the timer the activity switches to the listview but each row is equal to "0" not the time from the chronometer.

Comment: this code is what i put on my chronometer activity. `View.OnClickListener mStopListener = new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Timer.stop();
            saveTime = Timer.getBase() - SystemClock.elapsedRealtime();
            Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
            TableScreen.class).putExtra("Timer", saveTime);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    };'`

Comment: then on the listview activity I have this `protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_table_screen);
        int seconds = getIntent().getExtras().getInt("Timer");
        String[] time = new String[6];
        for(int i = 0; time.length > i; i++){
                time[i] = String.valueOf(seconds);
        }

        ListView lv = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView);
        StringArrayAdapter ad = new StringArrayAdapter(time,this);
        lv.setAdapter(ad);
    }`

Answer (score 0):

You just need to add to the list that you gave to the adapter and then call notifyDataSetChanged() on your adapter.

```
public void addTime(long time) {
    timeList.add(time);
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

Comment: so on the chronometer java file, I would create a variable to save the time once I stop it. for example. long saveTime; then saveTime = " " ; then that would put in the code you gave me ?

Comment: Post your relevant code so we can see what you have so far.

Comment: This question could be helpful too. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4540754/add-dynamically-elements-to-a-listview-android

Comment: This is also a fairly simple listView tutorial. http://windrealm.org/tutorials/android/android-listview.php

Comment: yes i have a listview working at the moment. I just created a random for loop where it would fill the list view with the String "Time" 6 times. so in the listview I have six rows displaying "time"

Comment: String[] time = new String[6];
        for(int i = 0; time.length > i; i++){
                time[i] = "time";
        }

        ListView lv = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView);
        StringArrayAdapter ad = new StringArrayAdapter(time,this);
        lv.setAdapter(ad);

Comment: now in the for loop, what i want is a way to save the chronometer time, for example, time[i] = ChronometerTime something simmilar to this. thanks again for your quick response Andrew.

Comment: Can you add just the Chonometer code to your question?