# Activity to search all music files (or a particular extension) in Android storage

Tags: android, file-handling

I am building an Android app that writes files in the format of my custom `.fire` extension.

I need to access them all at once and put them in a ListView. Could someone please help me to fetch them via an activity or Async Task Manager?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write an Async Task to fetch the .fire files from the folder into which you are writing them initially and dynamically add the filenames into the listview.

You can do something like this in your async task:

```
String state = Environment.getExternalStorageState();
if (Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED.equals(state)) {
    File root = android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
    File dir = new File(root.getAbsolutePath() + "/"+FolderWhichContainsyourFiles);
    File[] listOfFiles = dir.listFiles();
    for (int count = 0; count < listOfFiles.length; count++) {
        File file = listOfFiles[count];
        if (file.isFile() && file.getName().endsWith(".fire")) {                
            String fileName = file.getName();
            //Here you can dynamically add this name into the ListView
        }
    }
}
```

You need to use an ArrayAdapter and add elements to the ArrayAdapter dynamically. It is brilliantly explained here: [Dynamically add elements to a listView Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4540754/dynamically-add-elements-to-a-listview-android)

Answer (score 0):

if you want to find files recursively:

```
private static List<File> filesList = new ArrayList<File>();
public static List<File> recursiveList(String filePath) {
    try {
        File[] dir = new File(filePath).listFiles();
        for (File item : dir) {
            if (item.isDirectory()) recursiveList(item.getAbsolutePath());
            else if (item.isFile() && item.getName().endsWith(".fire"))
                filesList.add(item);
        }
        return filesList;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        return null;
    }
}
```

and to retrieve files in activity:

```
List<File> files = recursiveList("/sdcard/Music/");
for (File file : files)
    adapterFilesList.add("" + file.getName());
```