# Add items to ListView on Android in Xamarin application

Tags: c#, android, android-listview, xamarin, listactivity

I'm trying to remix [the base Android advice for adding items to a ListView](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4540754/419956) in a Xamarin application, but so far I'm failing.

In Xamarin Studio, I've created an *Android App* targeting *Latest and Greatest*, and all default settings. I then added a `ListView` to my activity and gave it an id of `@android:id/list`. I've changed the activity's code to this:

```
[Activity (Label = "MyApp", MainLauncher = true, Icon = "@drawable/icon")]
public class MainActivity : ListActivity
{
    List<string> items;
    ArrayAdapter<string> adapter;

    protected override void OnCreate (Bundle bundle)
    {
        base.OnCreate (bundle);
        SetContentView (Resource.Layout.Main);
        items = new List<string>(new[] { "Some item" });
        adapter = new ArrayAdapter<string> (this, Android.Resource.Layout.SimpleListItem1, items);
        ListAdapter = adapter;

        FindViewById<Button> (Resource.Id.myButton).Click += HandleClick;
    }

    protected void HandleClick(object sender, EventArgs e) 
    {
        items.Add ("Another Item!");
        adapter.NotifyDataSetChanged ();
        Android.Widget.Toast.MakeText (this, "Method was called", ToastLength.Short).Show();
    }
}
```

I build the app and run it on my Nexus 5 device. The application starts fine, I can click the button, and see the debugger hit the handler. The debugger shows no other problems, both `items.Add` and the `NotifyDataSetChanged` methods are called without error, and the `Toast` shows up on my device's screen.

However, the item `"Another Item!"` does not appear in my list.

I do note that there's one *big* difference between the linked question and my solution. Where the linked question has code like this:

```
setListAdapter(adapter);
```

I instead did:

```
ListAdapter = adapter;
```

Because the `setListAdapter` method isn't available in my Xamarin solution, and I had assumed the property setter was meant to do the same.

Long story short: what do I need to do to dynamically add items to my ListView?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are adding item in your list but the adapter isn't aware of that list. What you should do is add the item to the adapter:

```
adapter.Add ("Another Item!");
```

Comment: Excellent. That works just fine, solves my immediate problem. You wouldn't happen to have any insights as to *why* Xamarin allows you to directly add items to the adapter, as opposed to linked Java solution that requires a backing ArrayList?

Comment: @Jeroen: You can add and item to ArrayAdapter directly in Java too.