# ListView Items does not appear, Code works without Exception

Tags: c#, listview, xamarin.android

Why does my ListView not show the items from a extern file?

I work with a LV Adapter, `MainActivity`, one `axml` for the `ListView` and toolbar
and one `axml` for the Rows.
The `Main.cs` reads a `.csv` from the Harddrive of a Mobile Phone. The `Adapter`
contains the `FindViewById` method.

Can someone check what i forget or don't see?

```
[Activity(Label = "MyLter")]
```

Comment: einsatzListView.setAdapter(adapter), you missed this line

Comment: before einsatzListView.ItemClick += MyListView_ItemClick;

Comment: refer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32567237/add-items-to-listview-on-android-in-xamarin-application and https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/user_interface/layouts/list-view/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Programming Pirate said, you missed to give adapter to you `ListView`, after your creating new instance of `MyLVAdapter`: `MyLVAdapter adapter = new MyLVAdapter(this, einsatzlist);`, you missed:

```
einsatzListView.Adapter = adapter;
```

Comment: @My_yz, I'm pulling my head against the wall, it's still the same question....Remove the `[Activity(Label = "MyLVAdapter")]` from your `MyLVAdapter`, it's an adapter, not an activity. Maybe you need try to understand each line of code.

Comment: @My_yz, I finally found your problem............ `MyLVAdapter adapter = new MyLVAdapter(this, einsatzlist);`, you used `einsatzlist`, but you initialized a `einsatzList ` in `var einsatzList = new List<EinsatzDataModel>();` , and your data are added into `einsatzList`, it's the caps issue............

Comment: @My_yz, yes, `MyLVAdapter adapter = new MyLVAdapter(this, einsatzlist);`, change the `einsatzlist` to `einsatzList`, and then add the code in my answer, it should work... If you solve this issue, please mark this answer, thx!