# How to add a row in listveiw dynamically?

Tags: java, android, listview

I'm trying to create a row in listview dynamically  by giving external data.

- Each row in a listview has a **string data** and a **switch**. String data taken from an Edittext externally.
- I have a **EditText field**. I will input the data through this.
- I have a **button** . When it is pressed, the EditText content should be added to a new row of the listview along with a Switch
- While adding the new row , care should be taken to retain the previously added row.

*I got the code skeleton from web. This code is manipulated by me for my requirement.*

The following code adds the row dynamically but it is clearing the previously added row. Kindly help .  Thanks

This is my **MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
Switch sw1;

private ListView listView1;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.fragment_main);
    }

    public void getdata(View v) {
        EditText et;
        String dev_name;
        et = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1) ;
        dev_name = et.getText().toString() ;
        create(dev_name, null);

    }

    public void create (String str, Switch sw1) {

    Items   Items_data[] = new Items[]
            {
              new Items( str,sw1)
            };

      ItemsAdapter adapter = new ItemsAdapter (this,R.layout.items_row, Items_data);

       listView1 = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView1);
       listView1.setAdapter(adapter);
   }

}
```

This is my **ItemsAdapter.java**

```
public class ItemsAdapter   extends ArrayAdapter<Items>{

    Context context;
    int layoutResourceId;   
    Items data[] = null;

    public ItemsAdapter(Context context, int layoutResourceId, Items[] data) {
        super(context, layoutResourceId, data);
        this.layoutResourceId = layoutResourceId;
        this.context = context;
        this.data = data;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {


       View row = convertView;
        ItemsHolder holder = null;

        if(row == null)
        {
            LayoutInflater inflater = ((Activity)context).getLayoutInflater();
            row = inflater.inflate(layoutResourceId, parent, false);

            holder = new ItemsHolder();
            holder.txtTitle = (TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.listtext);
            holder.switch1= (Switch)row.findViewById(R.id.listswitch);


            row.setTag(holder);
        }
        else
        {
            holder = (ItemsHolder)row.getTag();
        }

        Items item = data[position];
        holder.txtTitle.setText(Items.tv);
        holder.switch1.setChecked(false);

        return row;
    }

    static class ItemsHolder
    {
       TextView txtTitle;
       Switch switch1;
    }

}
```

This is my **Item class**.

```
public class Items {

    public static String tv;
    public static Switch switc;

    public Items() {
        super();
    }

 public Items(String tv, Switch switc ) {
            super();
            this.tv = tv;
            this.switc = switc;
        }


}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are assigning an array with one Items object that you create with the arguments passed in `create()`. You should try something like this:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    private Items[] items = new Items[0]; //We're making this a field, so we can create a new array containing our new item.
    ...
    public void create (String str, Switch sw1) {
        int i = items.length+1; //plus one because we are adding one element at a time. If you'd like to add more at once, change the 1 accordingly.
        Items[] tmp = new Items[i];
        System.arrayCopy(items, 0, tmp, 0, items.length);
        tmp[i] = new Items(str, sw1);
        items = tmp; //use items like you would use Items_data
        ...
    }
}
```

This adds the contents of `items` to `tmp`, and then adds our new item at the end. If you'd like your new item to be at the top of the stack, we can simply:

```
System.arrayCopy(items, 0, tmp, 1, items.length);
tmp[0] = new Items(str, sw1);
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your adapter declaration. May be below code help you.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
Switch sw1;

private ListView listView1;
 ItemsAdapter adapter;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.fragment_main);
        adapter = new ItemsAdapter (this,R.layout.items_row, Items_data);
    }

    public void getdata(View v) {
        EditText et;
        String dev_name;
        et = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1) ;
        dev_name = et.getText().toString() ;
        create(dev_name, null);

    }

    public void create (String str, Switch sw1) {

    Items   Items_data[] = new Items[]
            {
              new Items( str,sw1)
            };

       adapter = new ItemsAdapter (this,R.layout.items_row, Items_data);

       listView1 = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView1);
       listView1.setAdapter(adapter);
   }

}
```

Check this link : [Dynamically add elements to a listView Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4540754/dynamically-add-elements-to-a-listview-android)