# Saving lists of strings in listViews (Android)

Tags: android, string, listview, android-listview, addition

I am very new to Android, or programming in general, and I am working on an android list app. In the app I want to be able to save recipes in a listView with their name as the thing you click on to open the layout with the recipe. I want it to sort of be like the alarm section of the "Clock" app on ios 9, where you can save infinite recipes. Anyways here's my problem I can save and add one recipe to the listView (internally saving every ingredient) but I can't save multiple. I tried: [Dynamically add elements to a listView Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4540754/dynamically-add-elements-to-a-listview-android) but it doesn't work with internally saved strings.

Here's my code for the "Create new recipe" :

```
package pixleworksgames.mylist;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Toast;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;


public class new_recipe extends Select_saved_recipes {
EditText name_of_recipe, in1, in2, in3, in4, in5, in6, in7, in8,
        in9, in10, in11, in12, in13, in14, in15, in16, in17, steps;
Button createrecipe;



TextView first_recipe, ingr1, ingr2, ingr3, ingr4, ingr5, ingr6, ingr7, ingr8, ingr9,
        ingr10, ingr11, ingr12, ingr13, ingr14, ingr15, ingr16, ingr17, stepsView, numbers, stepTitle, recipeTitle;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.new_recipe);

    createrecipe = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button6);// Declaring editTexts.
    name_of_recipe = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);
    in1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText2);
    in2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText3);
    in3 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText4);
    in4 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText5);
    in5 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText6);
    in6 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText7);
    in7 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText8);
    in8 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText9);
    in9 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText10);
    in10 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText11);
    in11 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText12);
    in12 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText13);
    in13 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText14);
    in14 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText15);
    in15 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText16);
    in16 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText17);
    in17 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText18);
    steps = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText19);


}


public void onCreateClick(View view) { //onClick of "Create recipe" button

    createrecipe = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button6);
    String filename = "First Recipe"; //Making filenames
    String filename1 = "1ingredient";
    String filename2 = "2ingredient";
    String filename3 = "3ingredient";
    String filename4 = "4ingredient";
    String filename5 = "5ingredient";
    String filename6 = "6ingredient";
    String filename7 = "7ingredient";
    String filename8 = "8ingredient";
    String filename9 = "9ingredient";
    String filename10 = "10ingredient";
    String filename11 = "11ingredient";
    String filename12 = "12ingredient";
    String filename13 = "13ingredient";
    String filename14 = "14ingredient";
    String filename15 = "15ingredient";
    String filename16 = "16ingredient";
    String filename17 = "17ingredient";
    String filename18 = "Steps";


    if (createrecipe.isPressed()) {

       {

            String nrecipe = name_of_recipe.getText().toString(); //Setting strings.
            String ing1 = in1.getText().toString();
            String ing2 = in2.getText().toString();
            String ing3 = in3.getText().toString();
            String ing4 = in4.getText().toString();
            String ing5 = in5.getText().toString();
            String ing6 = in6.getText().toString();
            String ing7 = in7.getText().toString();
            String ing8 = in8.getText().toString();
            String ing9 = in9.getText().toString();
            String ing10 = in10.getText().toString();
            String ing11 = in11.getText().toString();
            String ing12 = in12.getText().toString();
            String ing13 = in13.getText().toString();
            String ing14 = in14.getText().toString();
            String ing15 = in15.getText().toString();
            String ing16 = in16.getText().toString();
            String ing17 = in17.getText().toString();
            String ssteps = steps.getText().toString();


            try {


                //Creating FileOutputStreams, making the files private
                FileOutputStream fileOutputStream = openFileOutput(filename, MODE_PRIVATE);
                FileOutputStream fileOutputStream1 = openFileOutput(filename1, MODE_PRIVATE);
                FileOutputStream fileOutputStream2 = openFileOutput(filename2, MODE_PRIVATE);
                FileOutputStream fileOutputStream3 = openFileOutput(filename3, MODE_PRIVATE);
                FileOutputStream fileOutputStream4 = openFileOutput(filename4, MODE_PRIVATE);
                FileOutputStream fileOutputStream5 = openFileOutput(filename5, MODE_PRIVATE);
                FileOutputStream fileOutputStream6 = openFileOutput(filename6, MODE_PRIVATE);
                FileOutputStream fileOutputStream7 = openFileOutput(filename7, MODE_PRIVATE);
                FileOutputStream fileOutputStream8 = openFileOutput(filename8, MODE_PRIVATE);
                FileOutputStream fileOutputStream9 = openFileOutput(filename9, MODE_PRIVATE);
                FileOutputStream fileOutputStream10 = openFileOutput(filename10, MODE_PRIVATE);
                FileOutputStream fileOutputStream11 = openFileOutput(filename11, MODE_PRIVATE);
                FileOutputStream fileOutputStream12 = openFileOutput(filename12, MODE_PRIVATE);
                FileOutputStream fileOutputStream13 = openFileOutput(filename13, MODE_PRIVATE);
                FileOutputStream fileOutputStream14 = openFileOutput(filename14, MODE_PRIVATE);
                FileOutputStream fileOutputStream15 = openFileOutput(filename15, MODE_PRIVATE);
                FileOutputStream fileOutputStream16 = openFileOutput(filename16, MODE_PRIVATE);
                FileOutputStream fileOutputStream17 = openFileOutput(filename17, MODE_PRIVATE);
                FileOutputStream fileOutputStream18 = openFileOutput(filename18, MODE_PRIVATE);


                //Getting bytes.
                fileOutputStream.write(nrecipe.getBytes());
                fileOutputStream1.write(ing1.getBytes());
                fileOutputStream2.write(ing2.getBytes());
                fileOutputStream3.write(ing3.getBytes());
                fileOutputStream4.write(ing4.getBytes());
                fileOutputStream5.write(ing5.getBytes());
                fileOutputStream6.write(ing6.getBytes());
                fileOutputStream7.write(ing7.getBytes());
                fileOutputStream8.write(ing8.getBytes());
                fileOutputStream9.write(ing9.getBytes());
                fileOutputStream10.write(ing10.getBytes());
                fileOutputStream11.write(ing11.getBytes());
                fileOutputStream12.write(ing12.getBytes());
                fileOutputStream13.write(ing13.getBytes());
                fileOutputStream14.write(ing14.getBytes());
                fileOutputStream15.write(ing15.getBytes());
                fileOutputStream16.write(ing16.getBytes());
                fileOutputStream17.write(ing17.getBytes());
                fileOutputStream18.write(ssteps.getBytes());


                //Closing FileOutPutStreams
                fileOutputStream.close();
                fileOutputStream1.close();
                fileOutputStream2.close();
                fileOutputStream3.close();
                fileOutputStream4.close();
                fileOutputStream5.close();
                fileOutputStream6.close();
                fileOutputStream7.close();
                fileOutputStream8.close();
                fileOutputStream9.close();
                fileOutputStream10.close();
                fileOutputStream11.close();
                fileOutputStream12.close();
                fileOutputStream13.close();
                fileOutputStream14.close();
                fileOutputStream15.close();
                fileOutputStream16.close();
                fileOutputStream17.close();
                fileOutputStream18.close();

                //"Recipe successfully saved!"
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Recipe successfully saved!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                //Refreshing EditTexts
                name_of_recipe.setText("");
                in1.setText("");
                in2.setText("");
                in3.setText("");
                in4.setText("");
                in5.setText("");
                in6.setText("");
                in7.setText("");
                in8.setText("");
                in9.setText("");
                in10.setText("");
                in11.setText("");
                in12.setText("");
                in13.setText("");
                in14.setText("");
                in15.setText("");
                in16.setText("");
                in17.setText("");
                steps.setText("");


            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            //Adding the name of the recipe to the listView
            arrayList.add(nrecipe);
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }


        //Opening the Select_saved_recipes menu
        Intent intent = new Intent(new_recipe.this,
                Select_saved_recipes.class);
        new_recipe.this.startActivity(intent);
    }
}


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main_menu, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);


}
```

And here's the code for the Recipe menu :

```
    package pixleworksgames.mylist;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.HeaderViewListAdapter;
import android.widget.ListAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.ArrayList;


public class Select_saved_recipes extends AppCompatActivity {
Button addarecipe;


ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;
String[] recipes = new String[0];
ArrayList<String> arrayList = new ArrayList<String>();
private ListView listView;

public ArrayList<String> getArrayList() {
    return arrayList;
}

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.select_saved_recipe);
    String nrecipe;

    if (listView == null) {
        listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
    }

    adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, arrayList);
    setListAdapter(adapter);

    try {
        //Finding the name of recipe
        FileInputStream fileInputStream = openFileInput("First Recipe");
        InputStreamReader inputStreamReader = new InputStreamReader(fileInputStream);
        BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(inputStreamReader);
        StringBuffer stringBuffer = new StringBuffer();
        while ((nrecipe = bufferedReader.readLine()) != nrecipe) {
            stringBuffer.append(nrecipe);

        }
        arrayList.add(nrecipe);
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                //Opens the layout which displays the recipe
                Intent intent = new Intent(Select_saved_recipes.this,
                        Saved_recipes.class);
                Select_saved_recipes.this.startActivity(intent);
            }
        });


    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();

    }


}


private void setListAdapter(ArrayAdapter<String> adapter) {
    getListView().setAdapter(adapter);
}

private ListView getListView() {
    if (listView == null) {
        listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
    }
    return listView;
}
protected ListAdapter getListAdapter() {
    ListAdapter adapter = getListView().getAdapter();
    if (adapter instanceof HeaderViewListAdapter) {
        return ((HeaderViewListAdapter)adapter).getWrappedAdapter();
    } else {
        return adapter;
    }
}

//When someone click the "Plus" symbol to add a new recipe
public void onAddClick (View view) {


    addarecipe = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button13);
    if (addarecipe.isPressed()) {
        //Opens new_recipe
        Intent intentApp = new Intent(Select_saved_recipes.this,
                new_recipe.class);
        Select_saved_recipes.this.startActivity(intentApp);
    }
}








@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main_menu, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
}
```

Once again a remind you that I am very new to programming so my code is probably very messy. I hope someone can help!

Comment: Read more on `SQLiteDatabase`, `Cursor`, and `Adapters`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your goals:

- Display recipe titles on a `ListView`.
- View a recipe's details when you click on a list item.
- Dynamically add a new recipe.

My suggestions:

- Read about `SQLiteDatabase` and `Cursor`.
- You already seem to get the hang of `Adapters`, so that's cool.
- Save your recipes to a database instead of internally saved strings.