# Android Add Listview item dynamically?

Tags: android, listview, android-studio

i want to add listview item dynamically. i had done this but when i restart the app listview item disappear. How can i save this item permanently to listview. please suggest

```
public class ChatWithAttorney extends Activity {
    ImageView btnBack;
    ListView chatList;
    EditText etMsg;
    Button btnSend;
    String msg_to_send;
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;
    ArrayList<String> listMsg;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.chatwithattorny);
        btnBack = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.btnback);
        chatList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.chatList);
        etMsg = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etMsg);
        btnSend = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnSend);
        listMsg = new ArrayList<String>();
        adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.chat_list_text, R.id.tvSentMsg,listMsg);
        chatList.setAdapter(adapter);
        btnSend.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                try {
                    msg_to_send = URLEncoder.encode(etMsg.getText().toString(),
                            "utf-8");
                    listMsg.add(msg_to_send);
                    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: use local database for storing the messages

Comment: Your question is about persistent storage, not adding dynamic elements... That being said, there is a well written page called [storage options](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html)

Comment: Hello please check this link you will get your answer [Click Here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4540754/dynamically-add-elements-to-a-listview-android)

Answer (score 0):

Put those `ArrayList` items in a database or `SharedPreference` and read those items when resuming your activity.

Comment: can you please explain i an new to android. i have not used any database yet.

Comment: search for android sqlite or shared preference. they keeps your data saved so that you can reuse your data later.

Comment: and one more thing how can i add item at bottom of listview and auto scroll up when new message comes

Comment: when adding to to list you can specify position. like list.add(pos, item). also lookfor listview methods. list view or adapter should have a scrollTo method which takes a position as param and scrolls to that item.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Local database` , `SharedPreference` or `Static arraylist` for storing the messages

Answer (score 0):

AT the Time of Destroy Serialize the List data.
And Deserilize when Application Starts Again.