# Android Add custom items in costum ListView

Tags: android, listview

I am creating a costum ListView

[image]

In this ListView I have the a list.xml with an item which has an image and three text fields.

[image]

Now to my problem :P

How can I add this custom ListView ITEM to my ListView (after a Button from another activity is clicked) and save it somewhere like in SQL...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Dynamically add elements to a listView Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4540754/dynamically-add-elements-to-a-listview-android)

Answer (score 0):

Don't use ListView. Use RecyclerView instead.
https://developer.android.com/training/material/lists-cards.html#RecyclerView

You need to create adapter where you point proper XML file for an item

Answer (score 0):

**1.** First, create a custom layout `XML` for your list row item(`Image and 3 TextViews`).

**2.** Create a custom adapter class to populate your `ArrayList<OBJECT>` on custom list row `XML`.

Here are some good tutorials:

1. [Android Custom ListView with Image and Text](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/02/android-custom-listview-with-image-and-text/)
2. [Android Custom ListView with Image and Text using Volley](http://www.androidhive.info/2014/07/android-custom-listview-with-image-and-text-using-volley/)
3. [Android Working with Recycler View](http://www.androidhive.info/2016/01/android-working-with-recycler-view/)

FYI, You can use `RecyclerView` instead of `ListView`. Android `RecyclerView` is more advanced version of `ListView` with improved performance and other benefits.

Hope this will help~